# English translation of Iggeres Rabban Yochanan ben Zakkai

Tags: translation

Is there an English translation available of Iggeres Rabban Yochanan ben Zakkai?

Comment: What is the _Iggeres Rabban Yochanan ben Zakkai_ and where can we find the original?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I see previous comments were deleted. You can find the iggeret [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_Letter_of_Rabbi_Yochanan_ben_Zakkai_from_Jerusalem%2C_Introduction.1?vhe=Otzar_Midrashim,_New_York,_1915&lang=bi) and [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%99). It's purported to have been written by RYBZ to a Jew in Rome on the matter of the Christians.